# Como pegar a linha abaixo (próxima linha) em C?

Tags: c, c++, string

Bom dia pessoas, eu tenho um arquivo que contém diversas linhas, entre elas as seguintes:

```
REMARK Evaluations: CoarseFF Proper-dihedrals   Coarse Atomic Repulsion Coarse Compaktr Hbond_Strands   Hbond_Angle_Dist_var_power_Strands  Hbond_AHelixes  
Helix_packing_coarse    HB_COOPER_coarse    RR_contacts_coarse  Total Energy  
REMARK 914959: 119.706  63.2753 86.7273 26  237.053 28  2218.95 -48976  13.5677 933.999
```

Eu preciso pegar a terceira linha ali mostrada, a segunda em que aparece "REMARK". Mais especificamente, o último valor numérico desta linha, o valor "933.999".

Eu estou fazendo assim:

```
while(!feof(arquivo))
{
    fgets(linha_do_arquivo, 1000, arquivo);
    if( (strstr(linha_do_arquivo, "REMARK") == linha_do_arquivo) && (strstr(linha_do_arquivo, "Evaluations:") != linha_do_arquivo+7) )
    {
        sscanf(linha_do_arquivo, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %s", valor_numérico);
    }
}
```

Porém, eu queria saber se existe algo para pegar a linha de baixo, algo do tipo "if inicio da linha == helix, fgets+1", ou sei lá. Acho que dá pra fazer com fgets, mas eu não sei como. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Qualquer outra sugestão também é bem vinda! =)

Comment: Aparentemente não, se entendi bem. `fgets()` vai ler bytes, só isso, você tem que criar o algoritmo que deseja com a informação lida.

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer pegar o ultimo valor da terceira linha, bem, para fazer a comparação do texto inicial, pode usar o `memcmp`, ele faz uma comparação de bytes semelhantes ao `strcmp`, a diferença é que pode especificar o tamanho dos bytes a serem verificados.

```
float valor;

if(!strcmp(linha_do_arquivo, "REMARK", 6)){ // verifica se tem a palava REMARK nas 6 primeiras posições do arquivo
    int x = strlen(linha_do_arquivo)-1;

    while(linha_do_arquivo[x] != ' '){ // posiciona x na posição do ultimo valor da linha
        x--;
    }

    sscanf(linha_do_arquivo+x, "%f", &valor); // passa o valor para a variável valor.
}
```

Comment: O `strcmp` serve para comparar strings, já o `strstr` parece que procurar um valor dentro de uma string, pelo que entendi. Referencial aqui [Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)

Comment: e seu valor de retorno, é a posição da string em que começa a sequencia de o usuário deseja (caso a sequencia seja encontrada).